# Reading the contents of a dropbox shared csv file with Python

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am new to Dropbox API. A colleague has shared a dropbox folder containing large (various sizes between 450 MB and 17 GB) csv files. 
I want to read the files on Dropbox without downloading them. I tried many things including reading the Dropbox API tutorials and documentation as well as referring to Stackoverflow post.

My question is: What is a good way to read csv files shared by somebody else and what path I need to use to read them with pandas.read_csv() if size allows me or line by line if size is too large.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but ...

Quoting [Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, ...**
>
> filepath_or_buffer : str, pathlib.Path, py._path.local.LocalPath **or any object with a read() method** (such as a file handle or StringIO)

Quoting [Dropbox Docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#RESTResponse)

> **get_file(from_path,...**
>
> Returns
>   A dropbox.rest.RESTResponse
>
> **RESTResponse**
>
> Responses to requests can come in the form of RESTResponse. These are thin wrappers around the **socket file descriptor. read()** and close() are implemented.

Then, should be as easy as:

```
with client.get_file('/magnum-opus.txt') as f:
    p=pandas.read_csv(f)
```

Where `pandas.read_csv` calls `read` method on `f` ( dropbox file handler )

**Edited** thanks @greg

If you are [downloading file with Dropbox V2 API](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html?highlight=files_download) then you may check if `raw` property of the `request` response is on stream mode and has read method.:

```
_, res = dbx.files_download(path)
p=pandas.read_csv(res.raw)
```

sorry, I didn't try it, just try and come back. If not then you must use iterators and hand chunks. More detail at [Raw Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: The basic idea here seems right, but note that `get_file` is the Dropbox API v1 method, which is [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should instead use the API v2 functionality in the [Dropbox API v2 Python SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python), e.g., as shown [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L157) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dropbox-api/408/downloading-a-file#t=201706182153218033648).

Comment: @Greg, thanks. Now I'm on dangerous side because I didn't try it. IDK if dropbox response runs in stream mode. May be I should to delete the answer.