# how to read csv file from dropbox as a dictionary (as read from csv.DictReader() )?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, dropbox-api

I'm trying to read a csv file from dropbox using

> md, res = dbx.files_download(path)

as recommended in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618353/reading-the-contents-of-a-dropbox-shared-csv-file-with-python?rq=1)

This is the csv which I'm trying to read :[csv_file_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvTXS.png)

from `res.content`, I get data from csv file which is in ugly shape.
Is there any way to read data more in shape like using:

```
import csv
with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['name'])
```

I want to read csv file as a dictionary but all I get is the data as:[response_data_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hObu9.png)

Comment: The docs say that "csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol" so it should be easy enough to convert the dropbox content into something it supports? When you say "all I get is raw data" where do you mean from?

Comment: I shouldn't had used the word raw data. When I try to read 'res.content' with csv.DictReader, there is an import error, also 'FileNotFoundError' and prints the data as in res.content.

Comment: @Rup I've edited the question and added screenshots.

Comment: Oh - you don't want to be `open()`ing res.content because that's not a file on disk. (Or if you just need a quick fix you could write it to a file and open that.) But the best way would be to convert it into a format that you could pass into `csv.DictReader` without trying to `open()` first. If it's a single string then that might be as simple as splitting it by linebreaks but I don't know for sure (either what it is or how best to process it.)

Comment: Thank you for assistance. It led me to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution by converting `res.content` into iterable obj:

```
import csv
import dropbox

path = '' # file path which is needed to be read
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')
md, res = dbx.files_download(path)
data = res.content # data in ugly shape
# Now data is needed to be decoded from bytes to unicode and then str.split()
data = data.decode('utf-8')
data = data.split('\n')
# Now data is an iterable object, so csv.DictReader can be used
reader = csv.DictReader(data)
# Loop to get data using key value from reader dict
for row in reader:
    row['nameen']    # 'nameen' is the key value in my case
```